# Converting an approximation sum into an integral when sums are nested with dynamic bounds

Tags: calculus, probability, integration

Some function $f(x)$ returns a probability of an event $E$ happening given condition $x$. Simply inputting some value of $x$ and getting an answer is simple enough. But lets say that $x$ can take any random value with known bounds $a<x<b$. Now (I think) the probability of E occuring is the average value of $f(x)$ between A and B: $$ f_{avg} = \frac{1}{b-a} \int^b_a f(x) dx$$
So far so good. I can calculate the probability of $E$ with one equation without iterating and/or approximating, but I've encountered an extra layer of complexity that I don't know how to solve. My equation is $f(x,y)$ and I'm trying to find the probability of $E$ with $a<x<b$ and $a<y<g(x)$. ($g(x)$ is a simple linear function)

I hardly know where to start. I can make a rough approximation by iterating through values of $x$ and $y$ like so: $$ \sum_{x= a+1}^{b-1} \sum_{y=a+1}^{g(x)} f(x,y)$$ But I need an exact answer. I thought maybe from here I would be able to use the limit-definition of an integral to convert the approximation sum into an integral to get the exact value, but I am completely lost at what to do since I have never dealt with nested integrals and the dynamic upper bound of the inner sum adds extra complexity. Can anyone help me figure out what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can simply use
$$P(E)=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b \frac{1}{g(x)-a}\int_a^{g(x)} f(x,y)dydx$$
assuming that $g(x)\gt a$ for all $x\in[a,b]$.

Here is why:

Let $P(E|x)$ represent the probability that $E$ occurs for some fixed $x$. This will be a function of $x$, since the value of $x$ is fixed and $y$ is random. We have then that

$$P(E|x)=\frac{1}{g(x)-a}\int_a^{g(x)}f(x,y)dy$$
Thus,
$$\begin{align}
P(E)
&=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b P(E|x)dx\\
&=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b \frac{1}{g(x)-a}\int_a^{g(x)}f(x,y)dydx\\
&=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b \int_a^{g(x)}\frac{f(x,y)}{g(x)-a}dydx\\
\end{align}$$

That probably won't be much fun to integrate, though.

Comment: luckily I wont have to solve the indefinite integral, just the numeric integral. I've never done integrals with multiple variables before. How do you do the inner integral given one set of bounds, but two variables?

Comment: There isn't just one set of bounds, there are two: the bounds $[a,g(x)]$ for the inner integral and the bounds $[a,b]$ for the outer integral. If you are unfamiliar with double integrals, all you have to do is evaluate the innermost integral as a function of $x$ (the $y$ variable will disappear once you do this, since the integral is definite) and then integrate that WRT x.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Thanks

Comment: @Ryan No problem!